# SQL query - slow in SSMS, fast in MS Access linked table

Tags: sql-server, performance, ms-access

I have a chain of 3 views (view based on view based on view) created in ssms on sql server. The thing is, since I uploaded more data than usual query for final view takes over 20 minutes to return records when in SSMS, but when I linked the view to the MS Access it generated in 8 seconds.
Does anyone know what might be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: SSMS is just a client. It doesn't affect how queries are run. Where is the *query*? What did you do and what do you mean " uploaded more data" ? SSMS doesn't upload anything. Did you try *copying into the result grid* instead of executing a query? Did you use the `Import Data Wizard ...`?

Comment: The problem is right here. "chain of 3 views (view based on view based on view) ". While this seems totally logical it is one of the worst things you can to the performance of your queries. Nested views completely confuse the optimizer. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos they are talking about querying the view. And yes nested views is a huge performance hurdle. It is certainly possible that in Access it could be faster because the optimizer is confused about what to do when views are nested.

Comment: @SeanLange the number of views doesn't matter as much as the *content*. Using three nested subqueries would have the same effect. It's the *query* that matters, the underlying indexes and execution plan

Comment: @SeanLange the query optimizer sees the *final* query with views expanded. That's why the *execution plan* matters more than the views.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the OP states they have nested views, this is NOT the same thing as nested subqueries. And when you have nested views the optimizer gets confused. See the article I linked from Grant about this. And of course it all boils down to the execution plan.

Comment: @SeanLange I don't think the article contradicts what I say. It compares three nested views with a direct query. If you tried the same thing with three nested subqueries, you'd get the same bad performance. You'd *still* get an unnecessary join with details, which is what caused the initial performance problem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos on the contrary, the nested views could very likely be much worse than the horrible performance from nested subqueries. Regardless unless the OP provides us with some details we all just guessing. :)

Comment: @SeanLange try it. Compare the execution plans. It would be a surprise if the query optimizer didn't generate the same execution plans. Avoiding view due to some perceived performance problem can result in ugly designs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't need to try it. When Grant shared his article with me I tried it and was surprised.

Comment: @SeanLange in that case, I have a 5M table I want to try this on ....

Comment: @SeanLang phew - no repro on 2014 SP2. Nested views create the same awful plan, same IO as nesting the subqueries. 100 times worse than a direct query. The elephants are calm, the turtle keeps flying. And getting too clever with nesting anything is still a 100x bad idea

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos not sure why you are being snarky with me here. We are in agreement that nesting is a horrible idea.

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys. To clarify:
1. I created nested view 
2. I added more data to initial table
3. I've started testing query in SSMS and via ODBC in MS ACCCESS

The thing that bothers me the most that in SSMS nested view takes more than 20 minutes to display full results, while Access ODBC connection does the same in ~8 seconds. I would like to understand the process that makes ODBC faster than SSMS client connection.